# How to create internal value in a module using OCaml/Reason

Tags: ocaml, mutable, reason

I have the following module:

```
type userBuilderType = {
  mutable name: string,
};

module BuilderPattern = {
  let builder () => {
    name: "",
  };
  let setName = fun name => builder.name = name;
  let getName = builder.name;
};

BuilderPattern.setName("Charles");
Js.log(BuilderPattern.getName);
```

It accomplishes the following:

1. Creates type for setter
2. builderName object for setting + getting
   In addition I would like to:
3. Be able to retrieve name using a JS.log on getName function

However, in this instance I get back the following error:

```
This is: unit => userBuilderType But somewhere wanted: userBuilderType
```

Any suggestions as to how I properly set up the setter/getter is more than appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the tests you run that lead you to belive that the update is not performed?

Comment: Yes will look into, and report back in less than 6 hours.

Comment: Oh, I see. Posting the type error from the get go is also useful. In this case `builderName` is a function from `unit` to `userBuilderType`. You can't access its field directly. If you write `let builderName => { ...` instead, it ought to work.

Comment: There is a downvote on this comment. As usual, I think it is more beneficial to comment what part of the question caused you to downvote. I would be more than happy to tidy it up. Thank you.

Comment: Have edited question.

Comment: You are required to post your code here, not GitHub or any other site. [mcve]

Comment: Full code put in question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous problems with the code in your question, several of them purely syntactic. The github code makes a bit more sense, but the main problem you have is that you don't make an instance of your data anywhere.

I think this is what you want, where an instance is constructed and passed to the getter and setter:

```
type userBuilderType = {
  mutable name: string,
  mutable age: int,
  mutable phone: string,
  mutable address: string
};

module BuilderPattern = {
  let builder () => {
    name: "",
    age: 0,
    phone: "",
    address: ""
  };
  let setName builder name => builder.name = name;
  let getName builder => builder.name;
};

let myBuilder = BuilderPattern.builder ();

BuilderPattern.setName myBuilder "Charles";
Js.log(BuilderPattern.getName myBuilder);
```

But this also seems like a valid interpretation of your intent, where the state is kept globally (which is usually a very, very bad idea):

```
type userBuilderType = {
  mutable name: string,
  mutable age: int,
  mutable phone: string,
  mutable address: string
};

module BuilderPattern = {
  let builder = {
    name: "",
    age: 0,
    phone: "",
    address: ""
  };
  let setName name => builder.name = name;
  let getName () => builder.name;
};

BuilderPattern.setName "Charles";
Js.log(BuilderPattern.getName ());
```

In both cases the problem boils down to confusing a function taking a single unit argument with just a let binding, in various ways.

Comment: My thanks as always. Indeed, my issue is a misunderstanding of unit types. Somewhat unique to OCaml even though it's like a void in c++ etc. The above as well as https://reasonml.github.io/guide/language/function/ + http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html really helped. My thanks as always.